# How we can use GATT with classic bluetooth in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, wwdc

Apple present Core Bluetooth support for BR/EDR devices at WWDC 19: 
*«This now will allow transparent use of GATT with the BR/EDR devices»*

But I can’t understand how we can use the GATT profile while interacting with BR/EDR devices. BR/EDR devices use the SPP protocol, so how can we access to services or at least get notify while connection?

Apple schematically showed the merger of two layers (for classic and ble), but nowhere is it explained what is meant. It is only shown schematically that we can connect to BR/EDR device using CoreBluetooth. But how can this be implemented in practice? Apple’s sample requires knowing the UUID of services from classic bluetooth or UUID peripheral. I know only Major Service classes of device.

Pls help and thanks in advance

Comment: This capability is specifically for dual-mode devices; devices that operate with a classic and a BLE profile a the same time. Prior to iOS 13 the user saw two devices in Bluetooth settings.  The Bluetooth stack can now merge these into a single logical device. For example, headphones that use a legacy audio profile and a GATT profile for config will be a single device in settings. It doesn't change the ability of apps. You still need to use Core Bluetooth to interact with the GATT profile and external connectivity framework to interact with an MFi Peripheral using a legacy profile such as SPP

Comment: Does any one know, If I have such a device will I be able to transfer data faster, meaning can I request the data to go thorough classic BT interface (around 100kb) to speed up things?

Comment: @CristinaTheDev, your bounty is really asking a completely different question. Can you ask your question separately so the answer doesn't mismatch? Though I suggest you be even more specific about the device you're trying to communicate with and its capabilities. As asked, your question is impossible to implement on iOS. But depending on the device, there may be another solution. "Bluetooth Classic communication with a BLE device" isn't really a thing. They're separate protocols. What protocols does this device support?